# React css How can I use hover css in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to make hover in Picture Component 
I can't find it no matter how hard I try.

Please tell me the name of the css that uses the following guest house used by React.

```js
<Picture style={{marginLeft: "0px", marginRight: "0px", }} />
```

Comment: did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

you could use [radium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/radium) for doing this inline

or just use normal css or a library like `styled-components` and move away from inline styles